# How to use $Scope.push with unique ID in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering on how we can use $scope.push with unique ID in Angular JS.

For example I have a json file like var news =

```
{
'id':'1',
'title':'news_1_title',
'description':'news_1_description'
},
{
'id':'2',
'title':'news_2_title',
'description':'news_3_description'
},
{
'id':'3',
'title':'news_3_title',
'description':'news_3_description'
},
{
'id':'1',
'title':'news_1_title',
'description':'news_1_description'
}
```

I'm showing it :

```
<div ng-repeat="n in news">
<h1>{{n.title}}</h1>
<p>{{n.description}}</p>
</div>
```

and then i'll push only by one news to my directive and I want to show only news with unique ID, I don't wanna show news with similar id.

is that possible ?

Comment: You want to display news with unique ID like this - http://plnkr.co/edit/KVq4JExbuAmq27mB4JcZ?p=preview ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, but I know how to do that, and this deson't help I'm looking for to push with a Unique ID

Comment: You  want to push unique ID, But when or where. i.e on click of specific element or what?

Comment: for example when I click on a button ng-click I call a function that push an element

Comment: what i get from this is: you have a json, it has duplicated id's. when you make a click event you want to push an element. But which element? the one which occurs first?

Comment: I push all the elements of the JSON on each click, and I don't wanna show duplicated news